# How to show that $ G $ is a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

> **Problem:** Let $ G $ be a group that is also a smooth manifold, and suppose that the mapping $ (x,y) \mapsto x y $ is smooth. How can we show that $ G $ is a Lie group?

This is a problem from Spivak’s book, and he divides it into three steps:

1. Find $ f^{-1} $ when $ f: G \times G \to G \times G $ is defined by $ f(x,y) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} (x,x y) $ for all $ (x,y) \in G \times G $.
2. Show that $ (e,e) $ is a regular point of $ f $.
3. Then conclude that $ G $ is a Lie group.

I don’t know how to use (1) to get to (2). How many ways are there to show that a point is regular?

Comment: Does it mean that you need to show $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is smooth?

Comment: Yes, it suffices to do so. But I don't know what is the connection between 1) and 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $(e,e)$ is a regular point, you can easily compute the derivative of $f$ at $(e,e)$ and show that it is invertible.

Next if $(e,e)$ is a regular point, then by the inverse function theorem you know that $f$ is local self diffeomorphism of $G\times G$.

Consequently, $f^{-1}$ is also smooth at $f(e,e)=(e,e)$ and thus $x\mapsto \pi_2\circ f^{-1}(x,e)$ is smooth at $e$ where $\pi_2$ denotes the second projection $(x,y)\mapsto y$.

If you compute this last map, you will get that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is smooth at $e$.
The final step is to prove or use the following fact:

> If $\phi:G\mapsto G$ is smooth at $e$, then it is smooth on $G$.

which comes from the smoothness of the multiplication $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.

Comment: I agree with most of your solutions, but I don't understand the "easily compute" part. Is it really obvious? By definition, we need to choose local coordinates, right?

Comment: In local coordinates, the only thing you really understand in $f$ is the first part since $f(x,y)=f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_n)=(x_1,\cdots,x_n,(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\cdot (y_1,\cdots,y_n))$. Writing $df_{(e,e)}$ as a matrix, you easily get that it has to be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}I_n & 0 \\ \star & M\end{pmatrix}$. Then, you just have to check that the submatrix $M$ is given by the derivative of $L_x:y\mapsto xy$, the left-multiplication.

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought the only way to compute the derivatives is to write them out explicitly (but it's impossible here) while it turned out what matters are those two submatrixes. Here are two other problems and I hope that you can help:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607295/questions-about-manifolds